# Ошибка при открытии файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы, visual-c++

Пишу в файл:

```
FILE *file;
char* safile="D:\\log-file.txt";
file = fopen(safile, "w");
char buf2[1000000];
sprintf(buf2,"%f * x^4 + %f * x^3 + %f * x^2 + %f * x + %f = %f",aa1,bb1,cc1,dd1,ee1,ff1);
fputs(buf2, file);
fclose (file);

//далее для коэффициентов

FILE *filen;
char* safilen="D:\\1.txt";
filen = fopen(safilen, "w");
char buf3[1000000];
sprintf(buf3,"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",aa1,bb1,cc1,dd1,ee1,ff1);
fputs(buf3, filen);
fclose (filen);
```

если закомментить второй блок(для вывода коэффициентов), то все норм, а так ошибка:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00418b47 in Kursovik_double.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
```

где-то в chkstk.asm.

Это visual studio 2005, c++, переменные aa1,bb1,cc1,dd1,ee1,ff1 формата double. Все на скорую руку, писать красиво нет времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, стек переполнен потому, что у Вас создается 2 таких огромных буффера в стеке :)

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос исчерпан=)